# how to apply nth-child or nth-of-type only to visible elements?

Tags: jquery, css

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cYJ4C/)

here's the markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li style="display: none;">four</li>
    <li style="display: none;">five</li>
    <li style="display: none;">six</li>
</ul>
<div>next example</div>
<ul>
    <li style="display: none;">one</li>
    <li style="display: none;">two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li style="display: none;">six</li>
</ul>
```

and applying this css:

```
li:nth-child(3){
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

results this:

```
one
two
three
-----------------

three
-----------------
four
five
```

and I wanted the result like this:

```
one
two
three
-------------

three
four
five
----------
```

So, how can I apply the nth-child or something else to only visible elements?

Comment: just add ul {border-bottom: 1px solid black;}

Comment: Can you assign a class to the visible or not visible elements?

Comment: nope. and @radha I was initially assigning border-bottom for each list and remove last-child border-bottom to be none, so I need to do it with nth-child to li not with ul.

Comment: u should use jquery to fix this prb

Comment: have you tried using :not(:hidden) selector....

Answer (score 0):

I tried this;

```
li:not([style]):nth-child(3){
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Although it doesn't seem to work, shame. You cannot do this with your current markup only using CSS.

How are the `style` attributes set? You could either set a class along with their style and use that to select them and not the `li` or use javascript to do the border.